# Let Users Save and Display Locations on a Map

Tags: google-maps

I have a web site and I'm trying to implement this:

- Some users (let's call them shop owners) will put a pin (to indicate a shop) and describe what's out there. They can save as many pins as they want.
- Other users (customers) will make searches for shops.
- Searches will only consist of location names.
- For example, if a customer makes a search for "Champs-Élysées, Paris, France", the system should show him shops around Champs-Élysées.

Can I make use of Google Maps API (or Bing, if there is an API for it) for it? Or any other ways? I'm open to all kinds of guidance. So please feel free to comment on my requirements too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Allow users to click on a map and create markers in your database ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042531/google-maps-user-location/4045255#4045255)). You can show a javascript prompt to let the customer type in the name of the store.
2. Create a form where users can enter a city. Search through your added markers for markers in that city. Or even better geocode what the user types in and use the lat/lng in the database to find markers within a certain radius